# Clang Error, GrabKitLib.a no such file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

In my iOS app project I'm using GrabKit Library for importing photos. I followed each and every instruction to integrate the library GrabKit within my app but after final step I got this error,

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Deepak/..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/MyProject-biphcewlydbubuapltrppubuyjvx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GrabKitLib.a
```

Also the Grabkitlib.a is shown in RED under Build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries tab.

I am using `XCode 5.0.2`, and app is for `iOS 7`. If anyone faced the same the same issue or know the solutions please help me with this. 
Thanks

Comment: So the `GrabKit` library is built as part of your project/workspace (i.e. you have the source for it)?

Comment: Actually I created a demo app first and it runs successfully then I integrated it in my Project. I exactly followed everything from the Github instructions.

Comment: I haven't read the github instructions.  Can you answer my question please.

Comment: Yes, i integrated it as a part of my project but not using workspace.

Comment: And is the library being built (check the build log tab)?

Comment: Yes I built library successfully however the GrabKitLib.a under the  products folder is always red should be black. I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48067/discussion-between-deepak-singh-negi-and-trojanfoe)